# In Python3, does `import` work transitively?

Tags: python, import, programming-languages

In Python3, does `import`  work transitively?

For example, if a module contains `import A`, and the module for `A` contains `import B`, then does the module  import `B` indirectly?

Compared to other languages:

- In Java, some said that `import` doesn't work transitively, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677664.
- in C, `include` does work transitively.   For example, if a file contains `#include "A.h"`, and `A.h` contains `#include "B.h"`, then the file also includes `B.h` indirectly.

How do Python's `import`, Java's `import, and C's`include` work under the hook to have   differences?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it yourself ?

Comment: Yes. If you load a file, the Python interpreter will interpret the file. So if that contains an import statement, this will be imported. Furthermore if you have cyclic imports, this will result in problems.

Comment: The file will be imported but the methods etc will not be accessible if called

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. In Java, some said that `import` doesn't work transitively, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677664.  in C, `include` does work transitively. You pointed out that in Python, `import` works transitively. How do they work under the hook to have such difference?

Comment: @AK47 What do you mean by 
   "The file will be imported" and "the methods etc will not be accessible if called"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're importing a module to your namespace, Python creates a module namespace. This goes recursively; when you import `A`, it will import `B` and if it fails you'll get an error. Otherwise it will be accessible through `A.B`

```
# temp.py
def func_in_b():
    print 'this is B'

# temp2.py
import temp

def func_in_a():
    print 'this is A'

>>> import temp2
>>> temp2.func_in_a()
this is A
>>> temp2.temp.func_in_b()
this is B
```

Answer (score 2):

Import always imports the namespace of the module or package.

**Package**: A a directory containing `__init__.py`
**Module**: A file with the extension `.py`

## Modules

If you have a file named `a.py` with the content:

```
x=2
```

File named `b.py` with the content:

```
import a
y=3
```

In the interpreter it will be

```
>>> import b
>>> b.y
3

>>> b.a.x
2
```

## Packages

Packages are behaving differently(maybe not so intuitive, if you come from Java), having a directory structure like:

```
+ mypackage
+-__init__.py
+-test.py
```

A import of the package `mypackage` wont import the module `test.py` but only evaluate `__init__.py`:

```
>>> import mypackage
>>> mypackage.test # will fail
```

Answer (score 0):

C/C++'s `#include` works on preprocessor level. Java and Python doesn't have a preprocessor. They are more smart, their VMs know about any modules you can import at runtime. Imports there is a way to avoid conflicts of names. In Java you may not use imports at all but then you should define full class names every time (e.g. `java.util.List` instean of just `List`). Almost the same for Python.

Comment: Thanks. " Almost the same for Python." What are the same and what are different from Java?

Comment: @Ben, as I know in Python you always should import every module you use. But you can write imports anywhere, even within a function.