# isinstance fails for a type imported via package and from the same module directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

```
/Project
|-- main.py
|--/lib
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--foo.py
|  |--Types.py
```

`/Project/lib` has been added to the `PYTHONPATH` variables.

**Types.py:**

```
class Custom(object):
    def __init__(self):
        a = 1
        b = 2
```

**foo.py:**

```
from Types import Custom
def foo(o):
    assert isinstance(o, Custom)
```

Finally, from **main.py**:

```
from lib.Types import Custom
from lib.foo import foo
a = Custom()
foo(a)
```

The problem now is, that `a` is of type `lib.foo.Custom`, while the isinstance call will check if it equals `foo.Custom`, which obviously returns false.

How can I avoid this problem, without having to change anything in the library (lib)?

Comment: Irrespective of the import path, the class reference would remain the same. I don't think you should be facing any issue here.

Comment: You are missing the `__init__.py` in the `lib` directory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688216/in-python3-does-import-work-transitively/46688250#46688250)

Comment: + `types` is a name which exists in the std lib, I'd go for a different one.

Comment: `lib.foo.Custom` and `foo.Custom` are just two different references to the same class.

Comment: Either change the name, or if you must keep it the same, use relative imports `from .types import Custom`. That way it would be more explicit.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had an empty `__init__.py` in the lib directory, didn't think it was relevant though as it's empty.

Comment: `__init__.py` in your lib folder is actually relevant. Without this file, lib would not be imported as a module, thus `from lib.Types import Custom` would fail

Comment: ok good to know. Anyway, all the imports actually do work, but still the assert fails and pycharm debugging shows that `a` and `Custom` are different classes/types

Comment: @Antwane "relevant" is kind of an understatement. More like, "the key to the issue"!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should not both make `lib` a package and add it to `PYTHONPATH`. This makes it possible to import its modules both as `lib.` and directly, setting yourself up for failure.

As you can see,

```
lib.Types.Custom != Types.Custom
```

because of [the way Python imports work](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Python searches the import path and parses an appropriate entry that it finds.

- When you import `lib.Types`, it imports the `lib` directory as a package, then `lib/Types.py` as a submodule inside it, creating module objects `lib` and `lib.Types` in `sys.modules`.
- When you import `Types`, it imports `Types.py` as a standalone module, creating a module object `Types` in `sys.modules`.

So, `Types` and `lib.Types` end up as two different module objects. Python doesn't check if they are the same file to keep things simple and to avoid second-guessing you.

(This is actually listed in the [Traps for the Unwary in Python’s Import System](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap) article as the "double import trap".)

---

If you remove `lib` from `PYTHONPATH`, the import in `lib/foo.py` would need to become a relative import:

```
from .Types import Custom
```

or an absolute import:

```
from lib.Types import Custom
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't call it a "trap" because "trap" implies something actively counterintuitive. Accessing the same thing in the same place via two different routes is a stupid thing to do -- anywhere, not just in Python. So, this is rather a due punishment for bad design. Which is always a good thing -- it both teaches the botcher a valuable lesson and saves their users and peers from suffering from their mistakes in their stead.

Comment: Love this very clear answer. Linked to this in https://github.com/snooze92/confusing_isinstance after getting confused myself!

Answer (score 8):

When a module is imported thru two different path in the same process - like here with `import Types` in `foo.py` and `import lib.Types` in `main.py`, it is really imported twice, yielding two distinct module objects, each with it's own distinct functions and class instances (you can check by yourself using `id(obj_or_class)`), effectively breaking `is` and `isinstance` tests.

The solution here would be to add `Project` (not `Project/lib`) to your pythonpath (fwiw that's what should have been done anyway - pythonpath/sys.path should be a list of directories *containing* packages and modules, not the packages directories themselves) and use `from lib.Type import Custom` everywhere, so you only have one single instance of the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
# For generating a class UUID: uuidgen -n "<MODULE_UUID>" -N <Python class name> -s
# Example: uuidgen -n "dec9b2e9-07c0-4f59-af97-92f171e6fe33" -N Args -s
MODULE_UUID = "dec9b2e9-07c0-4f59-af97-92f171e6fe33"

def get_class_uuid(obj_or_cls):
    if isinstance(obj_or_cls, type):
        # it's a class
        return getattr(obj_or_cls, "CLASS_UUID", None)
    # it's an object
    return getattr(obj_or_cls.__class__, "CLASS_UUID", None)

def same_type(obj, cls):
    return get_class_uuid(obj) == get_class_uuid(cls)

class Foo:
    CLASS_UUID = "340637d8-5cb7-53b1-975e-d3f30bb825cd"

    @staticmethod
    def check_type(obj, accept_none=True):
        if obj is None:
            return accept_none 
        return same_type(obj, Foo)
...

assert Foo.check_type(obj)
```

Comment: Please could you add some explanation to your code?  What was the question asker doing wrong?