# Why does a submodule's code try to import a sibling submodule both directly and via relative import?

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a script that will be executable from the command line (by adding an `entry_points` argument to `setup.py`).  My directory structure is as follows:

```
# Edit: package hasn't followed src packaging pattern, renamed to root_dir
root_dir/
    conftest.py
    setup.py
    module1/
        __init__.py
        script1.py
        script2.py
    module2/
        __init__.py
        other_script1.py
        other_script2.py
    tests/
        conftest.py
        some_tests/
            conftest.py
            test_some_parts.py
        some_other_tests/
            conftest.py
            test_these_other_parts.py
```

Edit: My `setup.py` has an entry_points argument as follows:

```
    entry_points={
 'console_scripts': ['load_data = module1.script1:main']
},
```

At the moment, at the top of `script1.py` I have:

```
try:
    from script2 import func2
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from .script2 import func2
```

When I install the package (`pip install .`) and run `load_data` via the command line, it wants `from script2 import func2`. But when I run tests, it wants `from .script2 import func2`. I think this matters, but I run tests while in the `src/` directory (`pytest tests/`).

This odd `try/except` is a bandaid that allows me to run tests and execute my script. Is there a better solution to this or at least explanation?

Comment: You can just use absolute imports; if you installed the package as `pkg` then you can use `from pkg.module1.script2 import func2`.

Comment: IIRC this problem is because pytest does weird things with its execution location and how it handles imports. I don't know what the solution is, exactly, but kudos to you for figuring out this elegant of a bandaid - I never thought of this.

Comment: @a_guest, that's what I had originally, but I'll try again. @Green Cloak Guy I'm glad the `try/except` worked, but hopefully this doesn't propogate a poor practice haha.

Comment: What happens if you have *just* the `from .script2 import func2` version, with no try-except? (If you get a stack trace, please show us.)

Comment: This is strange. `from script2 import func2` shouldn't work unless `module1/` is for some reason in `sys.path` -- which it has no business to be in. You are likely a victim of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708659/isinstance-fails-for-a-type-imported-via-package-and-from-the-same-module-direct/46709896#46709896

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is correct:

```
from .script2 import func2
```

Remove the try/except hack. With a correctly installed package, `pytest` command should not care which directory you're in for the purposes of resolving imports. Note that `pytest` will add any directories where `conftest.py` files are discovered to `sys.path`, which can be masking or exacerbating packaging issues.

**This is a packaging problem.** You're doing the `src` layout wrong: `setup.py` should be *outside* of the src root.  The `tests` subdir should be at the same level as `src`. Re-read [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) or [this](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) and try again (and destroy/recreate venv might be advisable).

For a couple of examples of a popular open-source project structure correctly using the src layout, checkout [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) or [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography).

And, last but not least, don't feel bad for getting it wrong. Python packaging is a mess and it's extremely tricky to get it right.

Comment: I have messed up my presentation of the problem yet again. I should not have had the top level package be called `src` in my example. This project hasn't followed the `src` model of packaging, so the `src` in the example is misleading. I will update the post to reflect this. Nonetheless, your points are valid and I'm going to change the directory structure based on the articles you presented. I will come back with my results.

Comment: Using the link you provided as a guide, I restructured the project, added `package_dirs` argument to `setup` and `'src'` argument to `find_packages` function and it is now working like a dream. Thank you.