# How to import two submodules in python with the same subfolder name

Tags: python, python-import

My project structure looks like this:

```
project/
  main.py
  sub_a/
    class_a.py
    __init__.py
    utils/
      __init__.py
      util_a.py
  sub_b/
    class_b.py
    __init__.py
    utils/
      __init__.py
      util_b.py
```

And in each of `class_a.py`, `class_b.py`, there is an import like this:

```
from utils import util_a/b
```

My `PYTHONPATH` points to both `sub_a` and `sub_b`. When I try to

```
import class_b
```

in `main.py`, I get an ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name util_b
```

I am using Python 2.7.

I understand that the error comes about because `from utils import util_b` is ambiguous, so Python chooses the first one on the path, but how can I rewrite the imports so that they work?

I don't think changing the `PYTHONPATH` is an option, since each of `sub_a` and `sub_b` assume they are part of the `PYTHONPATH` in their own internal imports. For instance, the `from utils import util_b` in `class_b.py`.

Comment: Where is the problematic import statement?  Is it inside `main.py`? 
I started playing around with this in a repo: https://github.com/fireproofsocks/python_import . -- it's a work in progress but maybe one of the examples there will help clarify Python's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add both subdirectories to `PYTHONPATH`. Instead, add only `project` to it and import `sub_a.utils.util_a` and `sub_b.utils.utils_b`.
(In the packages themselves, you can use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=relative%20imports#package-relative-imports) to import things from the same subtree. E.g. in `sub_b/__init__.py`: `import .utils.utils_b`)

As per [isinstance fails for a type imported via package and from the same module directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708659/isinstance-fails-for-a-type-imported-via-package-and-from-the-same-module-direct/46709896#46709896) , if you add the subdirectories, `utils` package gets associated with whichever is earlier on `sys.path` and only it will be searched whenever you try to import anything from `utils`.

Comment: I don't think this quite works, since each submodule depends on its own imports. For instance, files in `sub_b` call something like `from utils import util_b`.

Comment: @mwlon use relative imports in this case: `from .utils import util_b`.

Comment: So there's no way to make it work without changing one or both of the submodules? Also, aren't relative imports frowned upon?

Comment: @mwlon A relative import is syntax sugar. `from .utils import util_b` in `sub_b` is equivalent to `from sub_b.utils import util_b` but without hardcoding the current module name. They may have been frowned upon when they were new but now they are supported by all non-EOL versions. See https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/ for pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is 'Import As'

Good overview here:
Answered in another thread [from ... import OR import ... as for modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245711/from-import-or-import-as-for-modules)'

from project.sub_a import User as aUser

from project.sub_b import User as bUser

Comment: I clarified the constraint that each submodule requires its own pythonpath to import from utils, which becomes ambiguous. How do I work around that?