# Catching local exception type raised by imported module

Tags: python, exception, import

I have a main module that defines a generic class, and a second module that defines a subclass.

When running the main module as a script, I would like to use the subclass from the second module. However I'm unable to catch the exceptions declared in the main module

```py
# a.py
class CustomException(Exception): pass

class A:
    def raise_exception(self):
        raise CustomException()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import b
    try:
        b.B().raise_exception()
    except CustomException as e:
        print('Caught as CustomException')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Caught as generic Exception.')
        print(type(e))

    # Output:
    # Caught as generic Exception.
    # <class 'a.CustomException'>
```

```
# b.py
from a import A

class B(A):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a second `CustomException` type is created when the second module imports the main one. [[1]](https://bugs.python.org/issue1249615) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708659/isinstance-fails-for-a-type-imported-via-package-and-from-the-same-module-direct)

Notice how the `type` of the caught exception is `<class 'a.CustomException'>`, and not `<class 'CustomException'>`. To show they really are different types, the following are all False:

```py
id(CustomException) == id(type(e))
type(e) == CustomException
isinstance(e, CustomException))
```

The solution is to not have the same value (`CustomException`) imported via two different paths (local name and from `b.py`). The script must be rewritten to avoid the circular import.