# How to deal with objects not beeing equal because of different imports

Tags: python, python-import

First a small example to illustrate what I mean. Suppose I have a class `MyClass` in a subpackage in somepackage. Suppose I can import in these two ways, because the sys path is set accordingly:

```
from somepackage.subpackage import MyClass as mc1
from subpackage import MyClass as mc2
```

then:

```
mc1() == mc2()
```

will return False. Because apparently Python thinks these are two objects of different classes as far as I understand it.

Is my reasoning correct here? How to deal with such sitatuations? This seems like an easy way to break code.

To make this a little bit easier, I give a more concrete example for this issue. The above class is actually part of a library. This library seems to relies on the fact that `somepackage` is on the syspath and directly imports from subpackackes like in the second line above. For this reason I need to modify the syspath in my application as well to include `somepackage`, so it will find the imports in the library when using it.

I think it's already bad enough that I have to modify syspath at all, but at least I didn't want to rely on this modification in my own code that I can control and import the library with the full name ("the regular way"). I then ran exactly into the issue described above.

I have `from somepackage.subpackage import MyClass as mc1` and create an object to the library code. The library compares the object with a second one it created after importing the class with `from subpackage import MyClass as mc2`. And then the code failed.

Do I just have to accept that the library relies on the syspath modification and have to import all libraries the same way? This is what I currently do, but it feels like really bad. Is there any better way?

How to detect such issues in general? I had "luck" that this lead in my use case to an Exception, so I found the problem very quickly. But in generally these sort of bugs seem extremely dangerous to me.

Small Bonus Question: Is there some guideline or something similar, which says that libraries shouldn't import stuff like this? Something I could just send to the author to convince them that it would be better to not do it like this. Because at least to me it seems like bad style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isinstance fails for a type imported via package and from the same module directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708659/isinstance-fails-for-a-type-imported-via-package-and-from-the-same-module-direct)

Comment: Or as a now closed [issue on the CPython GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/42236).

Comment: I think it answers part of the question. The guideline mentioned in the issue: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap is very helpful to explain the problem again.

But it doesn't solve my actual issue. I know the lib did it wrong, but I wonder what I can do about it.