# package import is not importing its dependencies

Tags: python, import, package

I just wrote a small package containing a class to use on jupyter labs at work, however when I try to import and use the class which is dependent on numpy and matplotlib, it says that np is not defined.

Even though it is imported into the file I am importing the class into, and I imported it into the class file itself that I am importing, and the `__init__.py` file for the package. I just need the class to load some data into a `np.array([])` via `np.genfromtxt()`.

I have made one package before and didn't have any issues but I'm new so am obviously missing something.

Here's how I get the error:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Elliot-Wadge/pl_class#egg=pl_class
```

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from pl_data import pl_data as pl
PL_data = pl.PL_data

flist = glob.glob("data/*")

dictionary = PL_data(flist,  skip_header = 4, unpack = True, delimiter = '\t')
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5l18.png)
[class file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u377N.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python3, does \`import\` work transitively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688216/in-python3-does-import-work-transitively)

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding you but I did import it in the file, I can use it anywhere else in the file without issue since it has been imported but as soon as I try to use a method in my class is crashes, oops this was supposed to be a response to the other answer

Comment: no that doesn't really help, I'm not trying to access something that I imported I just need the class to make a np.array([]) inside itself and it won't work.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: does that help?

Comment: Which line of this code gives the error "np is not defined"?

Comment: the last one dictionary = ...

Comment: in the init function it trys data = np.genfromtxt() with those kwargs, and that's where it fails

Comment: But the name "np" doesn't appear in that line. That's not where the error can come from. Please show the traceback of the error message.

Comment: You have to import NumPy as `np` in the file which has the line `np.genfromtext()`.

Comment: oh okay sorry I misunderstood, this is my first time asking a question what's the best way to share a screen shot? it seems like I can't just paste one. It's line 39 of the PL_data class if that's at all helpful

Comment: We don't need a screenshot, text is preferred.

Comment: You have to import np in the file where the `PL_data` class is defined.

Comment: it is imported in the file that contains the class

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: I'm not sure which file is which. In any case, in the same file which has the line `np.genfromtxt()`, `np` must be imported.

Comment: well I mean it's definitely 'physically' there but yeah obviously it's not otherwise it would work, does it need to be inside the class? I tried putting it in the init function and that didn't work

Comment: No, just put it at the top of the file.

Comment: okay well it's there, you can see it in the class file screenshot if you don't believe me, or you can just look at the repository if you're really not convinced, maybe it has something to do with the way I set it up or the way I imported it, idk but I feel as if this is becoming too specific an issue for stack overflow

Comment: In the screenshot of the error message, the error comes from line 39 of the file `pl_data/pl_data.py` which is `data = np.genfromtext(...)`. But the same file in your repository, https://github.com/Elliot-Wadge/pl_class/blob/main/pl_data/pl_data.py, has the same code in line 43. Apparently you are running different code than what is on GitHub. So it may well be that NumPy is imported in that file on GitHub, but not in the file that you are using locally.

Comment: Presumably, you are using [this](https://github.com/Elliot-Wadge/pl_class/blob/a9c4683fce22debc9bde553bfc9054d64637b5ed/pl_data/pl_data.py) version of the file, which does not have `import numpy as np`, you only added that in [this commit](https://github.com/Elliot-Wadge/pl_class/commit/48351fa189c2dcaa9e958c6431c59ef470d003f6#diff-1b53f545c5fa11a0749e0871777ecb716cf528f886238949315b299bc64af539).

Comment: ah good catch, I'm sure I can find it now, thanks